# Python 3 regex with diacritics and ligatures,

Tags: python, regex, diacritics

Names in the form: Ceasar, Julius are to be split into First_name Julius Surname Ceasar.

Names may contain diacritics (á à é ..), and ligatures (æ, ø)

This code seems to work OK in Python 3.3

```
import re

def doesmatch(pat, str):  
    try: 
        yup = re.search(pat, str)
        print('Firstname {0} lastname {1}'.format(yup.group(2), yup.group(1)))
    except AttributeError:
        print('no match for {0}'.format(str))

s = 'Révèrberë, Harry'
t = 'Åapö, Renée'
u = 'C3po, Robby'
v = 'Mærsk, Efraïm'
w = 'MacDønald, Ron'
x = 'Sträßle, Mpopo'

pat = r'^([^\d\s]+), ([^\d\s]+)'
# matches any letter, diacritic or ligature, but not digits or punctuation inside the () 

for i in s, t, u, v, w, x:
    doesmatch(pat, i)
```

All except u match. (no match for numbers in names), but I wonder if there isn't a better way than the non-digit non-space approach. 
More important though: I'd like to refine the pattern so it distinquishes capitals from lowercase letters, but *including* capital diacritics and ligatures, preferably using regex also. As if ([A-Z][a-z]+), would match accented and combined characters.

Is this possible?

(what I've looked at so far: 
[Dive into python 3 on UTF-8 vs Unicode](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html); This [Regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) on Unicode (which I'm not using); I think I don't need [new regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) but I admit I haven't read all its documentation)

Comment: Why not `pat = r'^([^,]+), (.*)$'`?

Comment: @Cristian: wouldn't that also match 'G@rd$tr%m, Joe'? Until such times I'll need to parse artsy twitternames, I'd rather not. Yet. But, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to distinguish uppercase and lowercase letters using the standard library's `re` module, then I'm afraid you'll have to build a character class of all the relevant Unicode codepoints manually.

If you don't really need to do this, use

```
[^\W\d_]
```

to match any Unicode letter. This character class matches anything that's "not a non-alphanumeric character" (which is the same as "an alphanumeric character") that's also not a digit nor an underscore.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I've been wondering about [^\W] negated shorthand classes. It says "can be used inside a class, but that is confusing", in Jan Goyvaerts' Regex [Reference][ref]. I think it's not much more confusing than regex itself.

  [ref][http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html]