# Slice regex back reference? Nocando?

Tags: python, regex, slice, backreference

Names in the form Nelson, Craig T. need to be split into

```
AN Nelson
FN Craig
IT C.T.
```

IT means initials, note the first initial is the first letter of FN, first name.

I already have a bunch of patterns in regex. For this one, I suspect regex won't do, the reason being: you can't slice a backreference

```
import re

name = r'Nelson, Craig T.'
pat = r'([^\W\d_]+),\s([^\W\d_]+\s?)\s(([A-Z]\.?)+)\s?$'
rep = r'AN \1\nVN \2\nsf \3\n'  

split = re.sub(pat, rep, name)
print(split)
```

will produce:

```
AN Nelson
FN Craig
IT T.
```

Ideally I'd somehow slice the \2, add a full stop and stick \3 behind it. I think this is not possible with regex and I should use a string operation, HOWEVER, it wouldn't be the first time I'd learn a trick here that I hadn't deduced from the [documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html). (Thanks guys.)

Comment: Just a general comment: do you really find `[^\W\d_]` more readable than `[a-zA-Z]`? I have to say I had to think about that character class for a few seconds. ;)

Comment: @m.buettner I think that the answer could be found in an answer to another question of the author: [Python 3 regex with diacritics and ligatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936315/python-3-regex-with-diacritics-and-ligatures)

Comment: @Alexey fair enough... I thought Python's built-in character classes only use Unicode properties if used with the `re.U` modifier.

Comment: @M.Büttner Alexey is exactly right

Comment: @RolfBly Please don't forget to choose the right answer if your question was solved ;)

Answer (score 4):

You may use one more group for the first initial like this:

```
pat = r'([^\W\d_]+),\s(([^\W\d_])[^\W\d_]*\s?)\s(([A-Z]\.?)+)\s?$'
rep = r'AN \1\nVN \2\nIT \3.\4\n'
```

I've also corrected having `sf` instead of `IT` for initials in the `rep` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of substituting, play with groups

```
import re

name = r'Nelson, Craig T.'
pat = r'([^\W\d_]+),\s([^\W\d_]+\s?)\s(([A-Z]\.?)+)\s?$' 
fmt = 'AN {last}\nVN {first}\nsf {initials}\n'

mtch = re.match(pat, name)

last_name, first_name, mid_name = mtch.group(1, 2, 3)

parsed = fmt.format(last=last_name, first=first_name, initials=last_name[0]+'.'+mid_name)
print(parsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say O never mind, but you were all faster :-)

```
import re

name = r'Nelson, Craig T.'
pat = r'([^\W\d_]+),\s(([A-Z])[^\W\d_]+\s?)\s(([A-Z]\.?)+)\s?$'
rep = r'AN \1\nVN \2\nsf \3.\4\n'  

split = re.sub(pat, rep, name)
print(split)
```

This is just a slight variation on Alexey's suggestion. Here, I'd prefer a real capital for the first letter of first name (VN).